# disable form submit until (two) checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, button

We have a form and before form can be sumbitted we have two checkboxes.

1. privacy
2. terms and conditions.

What I want to do, is ( having trouble validating with checkboxes ) is to disable submit button until both checkboxes have been checked.

the html for these is:

```
<label class="s_radio"><input type="checkbox" class="required" id="terms"/> <a class="s_main_color" href="/terms">Terms</a></label>
<label class="s_radio"><input type="checkbox" class="required" id="privacy"/> <a class="s_main_color" href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></label>
```

The js for validation for these ( not working though is )

```
if(terms == "") $('#terms').css({"outline-color":"#F12B63"});
if(privacy == "") $('#privacy').css({"outline-color":"#F12B63"});
```

Comment: ? if I am doing it totally wrong help is always appreciated. Its a very large form

Answer (score 9):

Jesse has a good solution.  For a slightly more concise solution that avoids duplication (you know, in case someone goes crazy and decides to add more checkboxes), you could do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.required').click(function() {
        var unchecked = $('input.required:not(:checked)').length;
        if (unchecked == 0) {
            $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice thinking, way more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

HTML

```
<label class="s_radio"><input type="checkbox" class="required" id="terms"/> <a class="s_main_color" href="/terms">Terms</a></label>

<label class="s_radio"><input type="checkbox" class="required" id="privacy"/> <a class="s_main_color" href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></label>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
 $("#privacy").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') && $("#terms").is(':checked') ) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
         } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
    });
 $("#terms").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') && $("#privacy").is(':checked') ) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
         } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
    });
 });
```

I can't promise that it's perfect, but I'm pretty sure that should work—if not, it definitely will put you on the right track.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

For the user's specific button:

```
 <button class="s_button_1 s_main_color_bgr" id="buttonsend" name="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled"><span class="s_text">Create Account</span></button>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#privacy").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') && $("#terms").is(':checked') ) {
           $('#buttonsend').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#buttonsend').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    });
 $("#terms").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') && $("#privacy").is(':checked') ) {
          $('#buttonsend').removeAttr('disabled');
       } else {
          $('#buttonsend').attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, our submit button is ...<button class="s_button_1 s_main_color_bgr" id="buttonsend" name="submit" value="submit"><span class="s_text">Create Account</span></button>

Comment: Should be pretty easy to change it so that works. I'll put the edited code in my answer at the bottom, glad I could help!

Comment: Just added the code to my answer. Working on JSfiddle here too: http://jsfiddle.net/jpollak92/LbxsM/. Glad I could help