# Accept Policy Privacy then enable form submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disable form submit until (two) checkboxes are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828006/disable-form-submit-until-two-checkboxes-are-checked)

It should be mandatory to mark the button "I accept privacy policy" to submit the form.

```
<form id="form" action="">
  <label for="accept">Accept Policy Privacy</label>
  <input id="accept" type="checkbox" > 
  <input type="submit" id="Send" value="Send" > 
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('input#send', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('input#accept').click(function(){
    var disabled=$('input#send').attr('disabled'); 
    if(disabled) {
      $('input#send').attr('disabled', false);
    }else{
      $('input#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }); 
});
```

You must search first, there are similar question in stackoverflow

[disable form submit until (two) checkboxes are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828006/disable-form-submit-until-two-checkboxes-are-checked)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5, you can use the required attribute: [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/m86nz/)

```
 <input id="accept" type="checkbox" required>
```

If you want a jQuery solution, here: [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/LPhGr/)

```
$('#form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $('#accept').is(':checked') ){
        $(this).submit();
    }
    else {
        alert('You must accept the policy to continue!')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try just to modyfi:

```
<form id="form" action="">
  <label for="accept">Accept Policy Privacy</label>
  <input id="accept" type="checkbox" required="required" aria-required="true"> 
  <input type="submit" id="Send" value="Send" > 
</form>
```

It will work in modern browsers, but for older (especially ie) You will need some Js to check it before send:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Send").click(function(){
        if(! $("#accept").attr("checked")) {
             alert ("You must accept the Policy Privacy");
             return false;}
    })
})
```

Comment: You're alternating the `"` and `'`, this way the code won't work. You should fix it.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Nice catch, I have update it.